# client side validations is not working on simple form for devise

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, client-side-validation

Client side validations are working perfectly on my other simple_forms. Code I am using in other forms is:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @group, :validate => true , :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

In Case of devise sign up form, Code is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :validate => true, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

I even tried:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@user, :validate => true, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

But its not working :(

My Gem file is:

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem "client_side_validations"
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form'
```

Versions:

```
 client_side_validations (3.2.0)
   client_side_validations-simple_form (2.0.0)
    client_side_validations (~> 3.2.0)
    simple_form (~> 2.0.3)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @bcardarella Any suggestions. Just came to know that you are on stackoverflow. Please if you can help me out. That will be great ;)

Comment: Are you required the client_side_validations javascripts?

Comment: Yes. Client side validations are working in all other forms except devise ones.

Comment: What do the `require` lines look like in your JS/coffee files?

Comment: @MattHuggins //= require rails.validations
//= require rails.validations.formtastic

Comment: That might be a problem since you're using SimpleForm and not Formtastic.  Try replacing `require rails.validations.formtastic` with `require rails.validations.simple_form`.

Comment: @MattHuggins Oh my bad.. But still same.. Its not working.. Even tried by removing formtastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would recommend upgrading to client_side_validations 3.2.1, which is about a month old, even though I don't see any devise-specific bugfixes in this release.

Second, they are both great packages, but know that the history between devise and client_side_validations has been fraught with incompatibilities. Look through [this search in the closed issues](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues?page=1&state=closed) for csv to get a sense.

Third, make sure you check out [this page](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Using-Devise) in the docs, which explains how to work around a javascript incompatibility with the email validation regex.

Finally, look through [this new example application](https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-devise_example) to make sure you are following the same patterns and practices.

Comment: Still not workin.. The example he provided works. But as I introduce twitter bootstrap.. Nothing. ;(

Comment: Ah - bootstrap. So did you run the `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap` command already? Also, have you tried taking simple_form out of the mix?

Comment: I assume you've seen [this comment/thread](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/286#issuecomment-5214797) already? It seems he may have found the right mixture of versions/elements, though sans Devise. There have always been several issues with csv and bootstrap. But frankly, even if you were to get bootstrap/csv/simple_form/devise to all play nice initially, I worry that it might be quite a pain to maintain that delicate balance moving forward. I've spent many hours trying to do this in the past -- hours I'll never get back!